# JavaScript Conditionals: confusion with &&

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am unpacking some data gathered from a form and setting object properties. If the input was a text, I am storing the value. If it was a checkbox, I am storing the "checked" attribute. If it was a radio and it was checked, I am storing the value.
Here is my code:

```
for (var key in assessment_data) {
  if(assessment_data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    var type = assessment_data[key].type;
    var name = assessment_data[key].name;
    var isThisChecked = assessment_data[key].checked;
    if (type === "text") {
      this[key] = assessment_data[key].value;
    }
    else if (type === "checkbox") {
      this[key] = assessment_data[key].checked;
    }
    else if (type === "radio" && isThisChecked) {
      this[name] = assessment_data[key].value;
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting unexpected values for some properties so I am stepping through it in Firebug and finding that the last `else if` is executing when it should not. For example, when type = "button" and checked = false, the code in that last `else if` is still executing. Here is a [screenshot of firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8m2e.jpg) at that step. You can see the variables in the conditional and their values on the right. Why is it hitting this code?

I changed the variable name in the question to be clearer and put up a new screenshot showing the code matching in Firebug. Also, here is the contents of the assessment_data object:

I found the cause of my problem (a bad conditional elsewhere: if(this.height_type = "Length") ).
I also figured out that the code inside the last else was not really executing as I though. Firebug was making it look like it was executing and I really don't understand why. The yellow > that shows you what line you are on as you step through was stopping at the line within that if statement, but the code was not actually running. I was able to reproduce this in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NDYR8/. I don't understand why it is doing that but for the time being I am happy.

```
assessment_date Object { value= "05/01/2013" , checked= false , type= "text" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: "05/01/2013"   

child_name  Object { name= "child_name" , checked= false , type= "text" }   
  checked:  false   
  name: "child_name"    
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     

dob Object { value= "05/01/2009" , checked= false , type= "text" }  
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: "05/01/2009"   

female  Object { value= "female" , name= "gender" , checked= false , more...}   
  checked:  false   
  name: "gender"    
  type: "radio"     
  value: "female"   

head_cm  Object { checked= false , type= "text" , value= "" }   
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     

head_in  Object { checked= false , type= "text" , value= "" }   
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     

head_unit_cm  Object { value= "cm" , name= "head_units" , checked= false , more...} 
  checked:  false   
  name: "head_units"    
  type: "radio"     
  value: "cm"

head_unit_in  Object { value= "in" , name= "head_units" , checked= true , more...}  
  checked:  true    
  name: "head_units"    
  type: "radio"     
  value: "in"   

height_cm   Object { checked= false , type= "text" , value= "" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     

height_ft   Object { value= "42" , checked= false , type= "text" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: "42"

height_in   Object { value= "42" , checked= false , type= "text" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: "42"

height_type Object { value= "Height" , name= "height_type" , checked= true , more...}
  checked:  true    
  name: "height_type"   
  type: "radio"     
  value: "Height"   
  
height_unit_cm  Object { value= "cm" , name= "height_units" , checked= false , more...}
  checked:  false   
  name: "height_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "cm"   
  
height_unit_ft_in  Object { value= "ft_in" , name= "height_units" , checked= false , more...}
  checked:  false   
  name: "height_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "ft_in"    
  
height_unit_in  Object { value= "in" , name= "height_units" , checked= true , more...}
  checked:  true    
  name: "height_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "in"   
  
length_type  Object { value= "Length" , name= "height_type" , checked= false , more...}
  checked:  false   
  name: "height_type"   
  type: "radio"     
  value: "Length"   
  
male  Object { value= "male" , name= "gender" , checked= true , more...}
  checked:  true    
  name: "gender"    
  type: "radio"     
  value: "male"     
  
reload  Object { value= " Clear and \n Start Over " , checked= false , type= "button" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "button"    
  value: " Clear and \n Start Over "    
  
use_head_circ  Object { value= "head_circumference" , checked= false , type= "checkbox" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "checkbox"  
  value: "head_circumference"   
  
use_height  Object { value= "height" , checked= true , type= "checkbox" }
  checked:  true    
  name: undefined   
  type: "checkbox"  
  value: "height"   
  
use_weight  Object { value= "weight" , checked= true , type= "checkbox" }
  checked:  true    
  name: undefined   
  type: "checkbox"  
  value: "weight"   
  
weight_kg  Object { checked= false , type= "text" , value= "" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     
  
weight_lb  Object { value= "47" , checked= false , type= "text" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: "47"   
  
weight_oz  Object { checked= false , type= "text" , value= "" }
  checked:  false   
  name: undefined   
  type: "text"  
  value: ""     
  
weight_unit_kg  Object { value= "kg" , name= "weight_units" , checked= false , more...}
  checked:  false   
  name: "weight_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "kg"   
  
weight_unit_lb  Object { value= "lb" , name= "weight_units" , checked= false , more...}
  checked:  false   
  name: "weight_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "lb"   
  
weight_unit_lb_oz  Object { value= "lb_oz" , name= "weight_units" , checked= true , more...}
  checked:  true    
  name: "weight_units"  
  type: "radio"     
  value: "lb_oz"
```

Comment: What if you break as shown in the screenshot, and then plug the checks into the console? Like test 'type === "radio"', and see what value that returns.

Comment: Is this reproducible in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I noticed the code on your screenshot is not exactely the same as the code of the question, my guess is that you are having a scope problem somewhere, check to see if you actually declared all the variables you are using with the 'var' keyword. The code of the question is right, there is no problem in it. As a side note if you are getting the isChecked value from a radiobutton or checkbox HTML element the checked property might be 'undefined' or 'null' instead of false when you check for it, but it's 'true' when it's checked.

Comment: @maaachine I tried evaluating them in console, same results: type === "radio" evaluates to false and isThisChecked === true evaluates to false.

Comment: @alex23 I added the object contents to the question

Comment: @RickViscomi , no not easily, but if I cant figure it out I will have to start taking it all apart at which point I may be able to put pieces in fiddle

Comment: @Hoffmann I updated the screenshot to show my most recent code. The last point you make is a good one, I'll think about that. At first glance it seems like that should be OK, but I will see if I can find an issue with that.

Comment: the first two set this[key], but the third one, the one that's giving you trouble, sets this[name] instead of key.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, thats what I want. In the case of radio buttons, I want the radio button name to be the attribute in the object. For example, there is a group of radio buttons for gender with names and values of male and female. So I want to just have one property in the new object called "gender" that pulls the value of the one that is checked. Regardless, I dont think that explains why that code is executing. I am trying to recreate in jsfiddle now.

Comment: Are you sure the line inside the if is being executed? The debugger can get lost on the lines indicating that the program counter is actually on the line below the line it's actually executing. I have seen it happen before, but not on firebug.

Answer (score 0):

i'd retry with the last condition beeing isChecked===true ...

that seems to be because JavaScript ist testing if there is a value other than false ...
So if your checked isn't set (which it isn't if unchecked, because it's a attribute without a value if set and not present if not checked) you'll still enter that else if, even if it's null.

Comment: Just verified, undefined and null are treated as falsy in javascript